# How to put two h3 tag and one div in same line?

Tags: html, css

I know this question might be asked so many times, but i couldn't find the one.

I want to put two h3 tag and 1 div containing 5 rating stars in one line, i don't know how to achieve that.

which css style can be added to achieve this?

Here is the code:

```
<h3>Shop Name</h3>
<div>
     <i class="fa fa-star active"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
                              
</div>
<h3>64 Sales</h3>
```

Comment: Create a container that contain all element inside and use `dispaly: flex` on that container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [FlexBox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

h3 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h2>Shop Name</h2>
<div class='row'>
  <div>
       <i class="fa  fa-star"></i>
       <i class="fa  fa-star"></i>
       <i class="fa  fa-star"></i>
       <i class="far fa-star"></i>
       <i class="far fa-star"></i>
  </div>
  <h3>64 Sales</h3>
</div>
```